# CA2000 error with 'using' statement. How to make this valid?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, using

The following code is giving me this code analysis error

> CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'SessionSummary.SessionSummary_Load(object, EventArgs)', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'entities' before all references to it are out of scope.

I am using a 'using' statement, so I am surprised on this:

```
    private void SessionSummary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var entities = new DbEntities(Properties.Settings.Default.UserConnectionString))
        {
            entities.CommandTimeout = 7200;
            var sessions = from t in entities.TableName
                            where t.UserSession.Id == _id && t.Parent == 0
                            group t by new { t.UserSession, t.UserSession.SessionId } into sessionGroup
                            select new
                            {
                                Id = sessionGroup.Key.UserSession,                                   
                                Session = sessionGroup.Key.SessionId                                   
                            };

            summaryDataGridView.DataSource = sessions.Where(x => x.Time > 0.00);
            summaryDataGridView.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
            summaryDataGridView.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You've actually got a potentially premature disposal, rather than a late one, as entities being involved in the closure assigned to the datasource means it leaves the scope.

You've **then** got an entities out in the wild that won't be disposed in its real scope, which is what the analysis is complaining about, but that's unlikely to be a problem compared with the fact that it is disposed before it is last used.

Options:

1. Leave it as it is. If the above works then it is **probably** because disposal doesn't affect the necessary state for the closure to work. This is dicey. Betting on "probably" isn't a good idea, and may also change down the road. (I can think of one case where using an object after disposal makes sense, but it's obscure and not what you have here anyway).
2. Force the query to execute eagerly. Calling `ToList()` or `ToArray()` on the query will run it and create an in-memory result that is then used as the datasource. At best though this will be less efficient in both space and time. At worse it could be cripplingly so (depending on the size of results you are dealing with).
3. Make sure the control completes using its datasource before the scope is left. Then clear the datasource. Depending on the control in question and some other matters (in particular, if it has an explicit `DataBind()` method) it can be trivial, impossible or somewhere in between to do this.
4. Put entity into an instance variable. Implement `IDisposable`. In your `Dispose()` method, call it's `Dispose()` method. Do not add a finaliser for this, as you are only disposing a managed object.
5. Create an enumerable method that wraps the query (and the using) and then does a `yield return` on each item the query returns. Use this as the datasource.

5 seems the best bet for most cases. It has the advantage of not changing the code much while not adding the (potentially large, depending on data) overhead of number 2. Note that just calling `AsEnumerable` (which has *almost* the same effect on execution order) would not have the same effect, as the closure would still be leaving the block unexecuted.

Edit: An enumerable that wraps the query would be like:

```
private IEnumerable GetSessions()
{
    using (var entities = new DbEntities(Properties.Settings.Default.UserConnectionString))
    {
        entities.CommandTimeout = 7200;
        var sessions = from t in entities.TableName
                        where t.UserSession.Id == _id && t.Parent == 0
                        group t by new { t.UserSession, t.UserSession.SessionId } into sessionGroup
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = sessionGroup.Key.UserSession,                                   
                            Session = sessionGroup.Key.SessionId                                   
                        };

        foreach(var sess in sessions.Where(x => x.Time > 0.00))
          yield return sess;
    }
}
```

Then you would set change SessionSummary_Load to:

```
private void SessionSummary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        summaryDataGridView.DataSource = GetSessions();
        summaryDataGridView.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
        summaryDataGridView.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will solve the problem, because `entities` never leaves the scope of the `using`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by 'an enumerable method that wraps the query and the using'

Comment: @esac have added a bit to my answer to detail this more fully.

Comment: I will try it as an experiment, my only worry is that I don't want to create 100 different methods for every linq query that I do.

Comment: Well it works, but then it throws an exception on the next line after setting the DataSource ... it seems that Columns[4] is returning null now.

Answer (score 3):

You are performing a LINQ-style query over `entities` **but are not actually enumerating over the result** within the `using` block. This creates a closure issue, since the query information stored in `sessions.Where(x => x.Time > 0.00)` is being stored in `summaryDataGridView.DataSource` and there is thus a reference to `entities` still in memory after your code above exits.

The explanation for this is that LINQ methods provide [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)*, which means that neither `session` nor the value you're assigning to `summaryDataGridView.DataSource` will be evaluated in the code above.

To force evaluation, you should be able to do this:

```
summaryDataGridView.DataSource = sessions.Where(x => x.Time > 0.00).ToList();
```

The addition of `ToList()` above will actually cause your query to be executed and the results to be cached in memory. Furthermore, `entities` will have gone out of scope and you will have no more references to it via any closure; so I *believe* that should do the trick for you.

<sub>*Note: this was just the first link I found from a Google search. It looked pretty good, though.</sub>

Comment: Sounds like good practice, but it didn't get rid of the CA warning by adding ToList(). Any ideas?

Comment: @esac: I wonder if collapsing the query into one statement would do the trick? Try: `var sessions = [ /*...what you have...*/ ].Where(x => x.Time > 0.00).ToList();` And then just `summaryDataGridView.DataSource = sessions;` Does that work?

Comment: Nope, updated it as you said, and still getting the same error.

Comment: @esac: This is really weird. You've got me scratching my head now. I'll think about it some more and get back to you. Maybe in the meantime somebody else will come along who can explain what's going on here.

Comment: @esac: Did you try any of the enumerable method possibility I suggested?